# Enable zookeeper on google app engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am new to Google Cloud Platform.
I have created two microservices and deployed into app engine. It works in GCP.
Now I want to enable microservices communications using ZooKeeper on app engine.
Could you please help me on achieve service discovery using Zookeeper

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine is not adequate to use with Zookeper. Since Java code runs in a limited sandbox, you may not be able to communicate with Zookeper at all. Also, you will have to start and end you backends programmatically, leading you to lots of work.

You can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281124/how-to-create-multiple-instances-of-an-application-in-cloud